# find specific array from database using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I have this JSON data in database

```
[
  {

    "total": 30,
    "List": [
      { //data//
        }
       ]
}
]
```

I need to fetch the `List` array and skip the items in it, with a limit.
How to get the list array using mongoose query?

Comment: `fetch the List array and skip the items in it` means only return the empty list? Please add more information to your question.

Comment: skipping with a limit

Comment: Suppose there are 30 items in this list, you want to return only 10 of them? the first 10 or the last 10, or the middle 10?

Comment: yes ,Model.find().skip((pageno-1)*5).limit(limit).exec() is using..i need to get the List from the json,only the List

Comment: As far as I know, the `limit` just affect the `Model`, not for the subdocument...

Comment: ok so i cannot use skip to subdocuments?

Comment: I am afraid you cannot use skip on subdocuments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no method to `skip` or `limit` on the subdocument.

So try to find the `List` from document like

```
Model.find({}, 'List', function(err, lists) {

});
```

The `lists` contains all items you wanted, then to retrieve any items as you wanted...

Answer (score 1):

Use `$slice` for pagination

```
$slice:[SKIP_VALUE, LIMIT_VALUE]}

{$slice:[0, 3]} //returns only first 3 items
{$slice:[5, 3]} //skip first 5 elements and return next 3 item (6,7,8 no.) items
{$slice:[10, 10]} //return 11-20 no. items
```

Mongoose Example

```
Category.find({},{List:{$slice:[5, 3]}}, function(err, limitedItems){
});
```

Here is my output for the query

```
{
    "_id": "56a34f0ef303a4271073183b",
    "categoryid": 40,
    "category_name": "find test",
    "__v": 0,
    "List": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "a name"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "a name"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "a name"
        }
    ]
}
```